# How could I limit the range of a variable in tensorflow

Tags: variables, tensorflow

I want to train a model using tensorflow.

I have the following variable which I want the model to learn it

```
Mj=tf.get_variable('Mj_',dtype=tf.float32, shape=[500,4],initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(maxval=1, minval=0))
```

I want the resulted value of Mj to be between 0 and 1. How can I add this constraint?

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this would be to pass the clipping function `tf.clip_by_value` as the `constraint` argument to the `tf.Variable` constructor:

```
Mj=tf.get_variable('Mj_',
                   dtype=tf.float32,
                   shape=[500,4],
                   initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(maxval=1, minval=0),
                   constraint=lambda t: tf.clip_by_value(t, 0, 1))
```

From the docs of `tf.Variable`:

> constraint: An optional projection function to be applied to the
>   variable after being updated by an Optimizer (e.g. used to implement
>   norm constraints or value constraints for layer weights). The function
>   must take as input the unprojected Tensor representing the value of
>   the variable and return the Tensor for the projected value (which must
>   have the same shape). Constraints are not safe to use when doing
>   asynchronous distributed training.

Or you might want to consider simply adding a nonlinearity [`tf.sigmoid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid) on top of your variable.

```
Mj=tf.get_variable('Mj_',dtype=tf.float32, shape=[500,4])
Mj_out=tf.sigmoid(Mj)
```

This will transform your variable to range between 0 and 1. Read more about activation functions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Activation_Functions).

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you're looking for is `tf.clip_by_value`.

Link to [Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value).